# Join txt files side by side in python

Tags: python

I have 2 arrays of data in txt files:

> A1 A2 A3
>   A4 A5 A6
>   A7 A8 A9

and

> B1 B2 B3
>   B4 B5 B6
>   B7 B8 B9

I would like to combine them side by side:

> A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
>   A4 A5 A6 B4 B5 B6
>   A7 A8 A9 B7 B8 B9

(The spaces are actually tabs in my txt files)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

something like this:

```
>>> with open("data1.txt") as f1, open("data2.txt") as f2, open("out.txt", "w") as f3:
...     for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
...          f3.write(x.strip() + " " + y.strip() + '\n')
```

**output:**

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
A4 A5 A6 B4 B5 B6
A7 A8 A9 B7 B8 B9
```

Answer (score 4):

Read lines simultaneously from either text file. Concatenate the lines you read each time, and write the result to a new text file.

Answer (score 0):

To abstract @Ashwini's answer to any number of files:

```
filepaths = list_of_filepaths
with open('path/to/output') as f:
    for lines in zip(*[open(fpath for fpath in filepaths)]):
        outfile.write('\t'.join(line.strip() for line in lines) + '\n')
```