# Merging two .csv files together side by side

Tags: python, windows, csv, merge

UPDATE ***** I solved using awk on Windows. Using this command to successfuly add files side by side.

```
call awk -F"\t" "NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1; next} {print a[FNR], $0}" OFS="\t" test1.csv test2.csv
```

---

I've tried this a few ways but still can't get it to work, I am guessing it is something to do with the special characters in one of the files. Using the `paste` tool, it's simple.

```
paste test1.csv test2.csv. > Test3.csv in Linux.
```

But I haven't got access to anything Linux-related for this task.

My environment is Windows 7, with Python 2.7 (No Pandas) and Perl Strawberry installed.

I need to merge 2 (or more) csv files together side by side. The files will always have the same number of lines.

I've tried this using python and it didn't work.

[Join txt files side by side in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123657/join-txt-files-side-by-side-in-python)

I've tried this using Batch and it didn't work.

[Merge csv file side by side using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072181/merge-csv-file-side-by-side-using-batch-file).

test1.csv contains

```
python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\
python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\
python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\
```

test2.csv contains

```
123456.pdf
123457.pdf
124587.pdf
```

What I want the output to be (Test3.csv) is a tab delimited file containing;

```
python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\    123456.pdf
python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\    123457.pdf
python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\    124587.pdf
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks you.

Comment: You said you've already tried various stuff - what problem did you encounter? Please post your current code and tell us what result or error you're getting.

Comment: What have you tried? We can't tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us.

Comment: How come you don't know what language you are using? Please fix the tags.

Comment: Just because you have Strawberry Perl installed doesn't make it a Perl question. You probably have a C compiler installed too, but C isn't tagged. Unless you have an example under a specific language, please don't tag spam. I'm removing Perl.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using `zip`.  You may need to play around with the delimiter and quote chars depending on the exact setup of your csv files

```
with open('test1.csv', 'rb') as t1, open('test2.csv', 'rb') as t2, open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
     r1 = csv.reader(t1, delimiter=' ')
     r2 = csv.reader(t2, delimiter=' ')
     w = csv.writer(output, delimiter=' ')
     for a, b in zip(r1, r2):
             w.writerow(a + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative and more intuitive solution using [pyexcel](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
>>> import pyexcel as p
>>> left=p.get_sheet(file_name='left.csv')
>>> left
left.csv:
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\ |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\ |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\ |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> right=p.get_sheet(file_name='right.csv')
>>> right
right.csv:
+------------+
| 123456.pdf |
+------------+
| 123457.pdf |
+------------+
| 124587.pdf |
+------------+
>>> left.column+=right # that's it
>>> left
left.csv:
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\ | 123456.pdf |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\ | 123457.pdf |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| python pdf2txt.py -o C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder\Folder2\ | 124587.pdf |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
>>> left.save_as('merged.csv') # save it
```

For huge data sets, above solution will be slow or impossible to complete. Hence here is the code to cope with huge data sets:

```
>>> import pyexcel as p
>>> left=p.iget_array(file_name='left.csv')
>>> right=p.iget_array(file_name='right.csv')
>>> p.isave_as(array=(a+b for a, b in zip(left, right)), dest_file_name='merged.csv')
>>> p.free_resources()
```

Answer (score 0):

The python pyexcel package has `pyexcel.cookbook.merge_two_files` (and `pyexcel.cookbook.merge_files` for merging N files).

(`pip install pyexcel`, see http://docs.pyexcel.org)